# setFontFeatureSettings error noSuchMethodError

Tags: android, css, fonts, typeface

I want to write the number in alternate fraction.

```
1
_<BR>
2
```

instead of `1/2`. for this purpose I used the code

```
Typeface typeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "Nutso2.otf");
vText.setTypeface(typeface);

vText.setText("1/2");
vText.setFontFeatureSettings("afrc");
```

but I am getting this error

```
com.example.kashif.equationsolver E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.kashif.equationsolver, PID: 4746
    java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: android.widget.TextView.setFontFeatureSettings
            at  com.example.kashif.equationsolver.MainActivity$3.onClick(MainActivity.java:331)
            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4438)
            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18422)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at     com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Only capitalized the I and fixed grammar.   What it needs is more code, not editing.

Answer (score 0):

[`setFontFeatureSettings`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setFontFeatureSettings(java.lang.String)) is sadly only available from Lollipop (21) onwards, you can't use it before!